# Error when trying to write unicode results from web scraping to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, unicode, web-scraping

I'm using a web scraping script (found on [GitHub](https://github.com/hakimkhalafi/trustpilot-scraper)), and write the results to a .csv file. Some of the results (user reviews) are written in Japanese or Russian, therefore I would like to write unicode to the .csv file.

The code works fine when I just use the csv module but this doesn't write unicode to csv.

This is part of the code I'm using for the web scraping:

```
with open(datafile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:

    # Tab delimited to allow for special characters
    datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    print('Processing..')
    for i in range(1,pages+1):

        # Sleep if throttle enabled
        if(throttle): time.sleep(sleepTime)

        page = requests.get(reviewPage + '&page=' + str(i))
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

        # Each item below scrapes a pages review titles, bodies, ratings and languages. 
        titles = tree.xpath('//a[@class="review-title-link"]')
        bodies = tree.xpath('//div[@class="review-body"]')
        ratings = tree.xpath('//div[@data-status]')
        langs = tree.xpath("//h3[starts-with(@class, 'review-title')]")
        dates = tree.xpath("//time[@datetime]")

        for idx,e in enumerate(bodies):

            # Title of comment
            title = titles[idx].text_content()

            # Body of comment
            body = e.text_content().strip()

            # The rating is the 5th from last element
            rating = ratings[idx].get('data-status').split(' ')[-5] 

            # Language is 2nd element of h3 tag
            lang = langs[idx].get('class').split(' ')[1]

            #Date
            date = dates[idx].get("datetime").split('T')[0]

            datawriter.writerow([title,body,rating,lang,date])
    print('Processed ' + str(ratingCount) + '/' + str(ratingCount) + ' ratings.. Finished!')
```

I've tried to `import unicodecsv as csv` but this raised a TypeError:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-2db937260285> in <module>()
     44             date = dates[idx].get("datetime").split('T')[0]
     45 
---> 46             datawriter.writerow([title,body,rating,lang,date])
     47     print('Processed ' + str(ratingCount) + '/' + str(ratingCount) + ' ratings.. Finished!')

~\lib\site-packages\unicodecsv\py3.py in writerow(self, row)
     26 
     27     def writerow(self, row):
---> 28         return self.writer.writerow(row)
     29 
     30     def writerows(self, rows):

C:\Users\Ebel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\unicodecsv\py3.py in write(self, string)
     13 
     14     def write(self, string):
---> 15         return self.binary.write(string.encode(self.encoding, self.errors))
     16 
     17 

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

I would like to have a solution for this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try: `with open(datafile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:` --> `with open(datafile, 'wb', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:`

Comment: Then try removing the `encoding` parameter --> `with open(datafile, 'wb', newline='') as csvfile:`

Comment: Your `with` is correct for Python 3, and `unicodecsv` is only needed for Python 2.  Just `import csv` (use the built-in one).  What do you mean "it doesn't write unicode to csv"?  If you are on Windows, you can try `encoding='utf-8-sig'`.  Windows Notepad won't display a UTF-8 file correctly without a BOM signature, and Excel won't read it correctly as well.

Comment: @MarkTolonen you are right, figured that out just now. Thank you.

Comment: @Silveris worked It doesn't return an error now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `unicodecsv` is writing bytes and not string, you want to `open()` your file in `binary mode`. Note that the `binary mode` does not need encoding, you have to remove the `encoding` parameter.

```
with open(datafile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
```

Then become:

```
with open(datafile, 'wb', newline='') as csvfile:
```

The `b` in `'wb'` means you want to write bytes and not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Making comment an answer.

Your `with` is correct for Python 3, and `unicodecsv` is only needed for Python 2. Just `import csv` (use the built-in one).  On Windows, Use `encoding='utf-8-sig'`. Windows Notepad won't display a UTF-8 file correctly without a BOM signature, and Excel won't read it correctly as well.